Can you circle beyond the published circling radii?
The FAA's TERMS/LANDING MINIMA DATA establishes a radius from each runway complex as airspace that is protected depending on the category of aircraft as specified in FAR 97.3. Is this circling radius a regulatory requirement to only circle if within that radius or can you begin the circling maneuver so long as you have the runway complex in sight regardless of your distance from the runways? If it is regulatory must you execute a missed approach if you find yourself outside the protected airspace as defined by the radius even if in visual conditions? Please provide FAA references, thank you!

Given that circling is already a not-ideal way to interact with an airfield, if you've got visual contact with the field at greater distance... why not just make a visual approach? If you really wanted to circle with that kind of visibility you could also just cancel IFR and proceed to enter the pattern for your desired runway?
